# SSIS - Best Practices When SSIS Hangs

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

Last night my SSIS hung. I'm not really sure why. This morning I identified which package hung based on the output. I'm looking at `sp_who2`, but I can't see any processes that are running under the user the runs the jobs.
I'm wondering what I should be doing when my SSIS just hangs. It's still currently running, but doesn't seem to be running anything.

Comment: How are you executing the package? Directly from visual studio debug, SSIS catalog or dtexec? Can you pinpoint the step that hung? If debugging, any breakpoint set? Any problems with external validations that might hung? Any calls to another .exe (or such) that might be waiting until it finished on a synchronous call? We need lots of more info here.

Answer (score 5):

Start off with deploying the package to SSISDB and running it from there.  If you haven't already installed the SSISDB catalog more information on this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-2017).  After this enable logging in the package and review the results, specifically the phases in which the package is hanging.  When doing this look for the `PipelineComponentTime` event which specifies how long each component took in a particular phase.  A couple phases that may be of interest are the `ProcessInput`  phase, which is where incoming records are processed, as well as the `PrimeOutput` that's where the data is placed into buffers and sent further down the the data flow.  An overview of enabling logging is as follows.

- Right Click anywhere on the Control Flow and press `Logging...`
- Check the check-box next to the package in the Containers field to enable logging. 
  Choose where you want the logging records to stored using the Provider Type field.  If you use the SSIS log provider for SQL Server the `SYSSSISLOG` table will be created in the database that's set as the Initial Catalog in the OLE DB Connection Manager that is used.  On the Details pane select events that you will log.  After selecting these click on the `Advanced>>` button to set the fields that will be logged.
- Next check whichever components that you want to enable logging for.  You'll want to do this for any components that you either suspect or have confirmed are encountering delays.  If any Data Flow Tasks have logging enabled, the `PipelineComponentTime` event mentioned earlier will be available under the Details window on these.
- For monitoring the package from SSIS catalog use the SSISDB DMVs.  When doing this make sure that the Logging Level is set to at least basic when the package is executed.  There are several ways to do this, with the easiest probably being from the GUI.  Before executing the package on the Execute Package window in SSISDB, the Logging Level field can be found on the Advanced tab.
- If the package is deployed to SSISDB and ran as a job in SQL Agent the logging can be set from the job step.  Open the Job Step Properties window, go the the Configuration tab and then the Advanced tab where you'll see the Logging Level field.
- There are many DMVs in SSISDB that hold details regarding package configuration and execution.  `catalog.event_messages`, `executable_statistics`, and `catalog.operation_messages` are a few that will be helpful.  For more insight on the components and where the delays are occurring I'd recommend `catalog.execution_component_phases`, which will require a logging level of either Performance or Verbose.
- If the performance varies depending on what parameters are used within the package, use the `execution_id` from the instances of the slower executions to query the `catalog.execution_parameter_values` DMV to see what the parameters are set to in these executions.

Comment: I wonder how the OP did not upvote this answer after all this effort you've done. +1

Comment: Thanks @Hadi, I appreciate the feedback.